# Standards or widespread guidelines for updating of Exif or other metadata when modifying photos or other images?

Tags: metadata, file-management, photo-management

I'm working on software that allows users to upload photos (or, potentially, any image). The photos are scaled to a maximum size (to save space) and as part of that change to the image I want to copy the Exif metadata from the original image to the resized image. If I do so however at least some of the metadata will no longer reflect the resized image (e.g. dimensions). Should I also update that metadata or should I simply preserve the original data?

Are there any standards or guidelines with regard to what metadata *should* be modified when editing an image; what *should not* be modified?

For my particular circumstances, the original image will *not* be retained by my software (tho it may or may not by the creator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad answer is to use [Metadata Working Group guidelines](http://www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf) (PDF). Specifically, yes, the metadata should include the new image size, as well as the Modification Date/Time.